# (0,0) Object reference not set to an instance of an object Unity 2018.1.2.f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, compilation

[Compile Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GOBU.png)

ECS project not compiling. Getting the error as `The associated script can not be loaded. Please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script.`

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: more information needed to answer, this scripts belongs to? which gameobject is supoused to use it? etc

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that your class name does not match your .cs file name. The only way to change class names is to change the filename within the Unity Editor FIRST, wait for reload, edit class name within the .cs file. Doing it in another order, or changing only the filename or only the class name will give you the mentioned error.

To fix the error change your class name to match the filename and re-add the component

Comment: I try on Empty Project but still not working. I have same errors." (0,0): Unable to start the incremental compiler service:System.Exception: Subscribe exception: EAGAIN(11): Resource temporarily unavailable
System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart()"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with Entities version 0.0.12-preview 4 :

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "com.unity.entities": "0.0.12-preview.4"
    }, 
    "registry": "https://packages.unity.com", 
    "testables": [
        "com.unity.collections", 
        "com.unity.entities", 
        "com.unity.jobs"
    ]
}
```